# Creating a function to replace NaN value by traversing up hierarchy columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function, hierarchy

I have 2 separate dataframes, data1 and df_attr.Where for df1, there is hierarchy data, where df1.manager_01_email is at the top of the hierarchy while df1.manager_04_email represents the lowest hierarchy

```
data1 = [["quarter","employee_id", "supervisor_email", "manager_01_email", "manager_02_email","manager_03_email","manager_04_email"],
         [["y2022q1",1011, "steve.g@pool.com", "fsg@pool.com", "m.edwards@pool.com", "dirk.k@pool.com","steve.g@pool.com"], 
          ["y2022q1",1012, "x.alonso@pool.com", "fsg@pool.com","m.edwards@pool.com","kenny.d@pool.com", "x.alonso@pool.com"],
          ["y2022q2",1013, "kenny.d@pool.com" ,"fsg@pool.com", "m.edwards@pool.com", "kenny.d@pool.com", "kenny.d@pool.com"],
          ["y2022q2",1011, "brendan.r@pool.com","fsg@pool.com", "m.edwards@pool.com", "brendan.r@pool.com", "brendan.r@pool.com"],
          ["y2022q2",1012, "dirk.k@pool.com", "fsg@pool.com", "m.edwards@pool.com", "dirk.k@pool.com","dirk.k@pool.com"]]]


data_attr = [["quarter","supervisor_email", "attrition_rate"],
         [ ["y2022q1","m.edwards@pool.com", 0.3], ["y2022q2","m.edwards@pool.com", 0.6],["y2022q1","kenny.d@pool.com", 0.25],["y2022q2","kenny.d@pool.com", 0.1],["y2022q1","brendan.r@pool.com", 0.7],["y2022q2","brendan.r@pool.com", 0.35],["y2022q2","dirk.k@pool.com", np.NaN],["y2022q1","steve.g@pool.com", 0.1],["y2022q2","steve.g@pool.com", 0.8]]]


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1[1], columns=data1[0])
df_attr = pd.DataFrame(data=data_attr[1], columns=data_attr[0])
```

I would need the "attrition_rate" column from data_attr df but due to NaN values and also missing values for attrition_rate, I would need to create a function to handle NaN values

For example, for "employee_id" = 1012, his supervisor_email "dirk.k@pool.com" has NaN value in df_attr.attrition_rate at y2022q2, I will need to fill it with the attrition_rate value of the manager in the higher hierarchy, but because "dirk.k@pool.com" is found at both manager_04_email and manager_03_email, we have to then traverse up the next hierarchy which is manager_02_email of "m.edwards@pool.com" at y2022q2

and for "employeed_id" = 1012, his supervisor_email "x.alonso@pool.com" is not found in df_attr, so his attrition_rate value is NaN after merging. I will need to fill it with the attrition_rate value of the manager in higher hierarchy, which in this case is "kenny.d@pool.com" at y2022q1

The outcome I would like to achieve is

```
outcome = [["quarter","employee_id", "supervisor_email", "manager_01_email", "manager_02_email","manager_03_email","manager_04_email", "mgr_attrition_rate"],
         [["y2022q1",1011, "steve.g@pool.com", "fsg@pool.com", "m.edwards@pool.com", "dirk.k@pool.com","steve.g@pool.com", 0.1], 
          ["y2022q1",1012, "x.alonso@pool.com", "fsg@pool.com","m.edwards@pool.com","kenny.d@pool.com", "x.alonso@pool.com", 0.25],
          ["y2022q2",1013, "kenny.d@pool.com" ,"fsg@pool.com", "m.edwards@pool.com", "kenny.d@pool.com", "kenny.d@pool.com", 0.1],
          ["y2022q2",1011, "brendan.r@pool.com","fsg@pool.com", "m.edwards@pool.com", "brendan.r@pool.com", "brendan.r@pool.com", 0.35],
          ["y2022q2",1012, "dirk.k@pool.com", "fsg@pool.com", "m.edwards@pool.com", "dirk.k@pool.com","dirk.k@pool.com", 0.6]]]

df_outcome = pd.DataFrame(data=outcome[1], columns=outcome[0])
```

I have tried based on the suggestion but am still not able to get it, appreciate any form of help or assistance, thank you.

```
# Merge dataframes based on quarter and supervisor_email
df_outcome = pd.merge(df1, df_attr, how='left',left_on=['quarter','supervisor_email'],right_on=['quarter','supervisor_email'])

#create function to handle NaNs
def fill_nan_with_higher_manager(row):
        if pd.isna(row['attrition_rate']):
            for i in range(4, 0, -1):
                higher_manager_email = row[f'manager_0{i}_email']
                if pd.notna(higher_manager_email):
                    higher_manager_attrition = df_attr.loc[(df_attr["supervisor_email"] == higher_manager_email) & (df_attr["quarter"] == higher_manager_quarter), 'attrition_rate']
                    if not higher_manager_attrition.empty:
                        return higher_manager_attrition.values[0]
        return row['attrition_rate']

df_outcome['attrition_rate'] = df_outcome.apply(fill_nan_with_higher_manager, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You need to handle the cases where you might have NaN. For this, I created a function that will handle these case. You can of course move it outside the `merge_attrition_rates` function if you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = [["employee_id", "supervisor_email", "manager_01_email", "manager_02_email","manager_03_email","manager_04_email"],
         [[1011, "steve.g@pool.com", "fsg@pool.com", "m.edwards@pool.com", "dirk.k@pool.com","steve.g@pool.com"], 
          [1012, "x.alonso@pool.com", "fsg@pool.com","m.edwards@pool.com","kenny.d@pool.com", "x.alonso@pool.com"],
          [1013, "kenny.d@pool.com" ,"fsg@pool.com", "m.edwards@pool.com", "kenny.d@pool.com", "kenny.d@pool.com"],
          [1014, "brendan.r@pool.com","fsg@pool.com", "m.edwards@pool.com", "brendan.r@pool.com", "brendan.r@pool.com"],
          [1015, "dirk.k@pool.com", "fsg@pool.com", "m.edwards@pool.com", "dirk.k@pool.com","dirk.k@pool.com"]]]

data_attr = [["supervisor_email", "attrition_rate"],
         [ ["m.edwards@pool.com", 0.3], ["kenny.d@pool.com", 0.25],["brendan.r@pool.com", 0.35],
          ["dirk.k@pool.com", np.NaN],["steve.g@pool.com", 0.1]]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1[1], columns=data1[0])
df_attr = pd.DataFrame(data=data_attr[1], columns=data_attr[0])

def merge_attrition_rates(df1, df_attr):
    """
    Merges the 'attrition_rate' column from df_attr into df1 based on supervisor_email.
    Handles NaN values and missing supervisor emails.

    Args:
        df1 (pd.DataFrame): Hierarchy dataframe with columns 'employee_id', 'supervisor_email', and others.
        df_attr (pd.DataFrame): Attributes dataframe with columns 'supervisor_email' and 'attrition_rate'.

    Returns:
        pd.DataFrame: Merged dataframe with the 'attrition_rate' column added to df1.
    """
    df_outcome = pd.merge(df1, df_attr, on='supervisor_email', how='left', suffixes=('', '_supervisor'))

    def fill_nan_with_higher_manager(row):
        if pd.isna(row['attrition_rate']):
            for i in range(4, 0, -1):
                manager_email = row[f'manager_0{i}_email']
                if pd.notna(manager_email):
                    manager_attrition = df_attr.loc[df_attr['supervisor_email'] == manager_email, 'attrition_rate']
                    if not manager_attrition.empty:
                        return manager_attrition.values[0]
        return row['attrition_rate']

    df_outcome['attrition_rate'] = df_outcome.apply(fill_nan_with_higher_manager, axis=1)

    missing_supervisors = df_outcome[df_outcome['attrition_rate'].isna()]['supervisor_email']
    df_outcome.loc[df_outcome['supervisor_email'].isin(missing_supervisors), 'attrition_rate'] = df_outcome.loc[df_outcome['supervisor_email'].isin(missing_supervisors), 'manager_01_email'].map(df_attr.set_index('supervisor_email')['attrition_rate'])

    return df_outcome

df_outcome = merge_attrition_rates(df1, df_attr)
print(df_outcome)
```

This will return

```
 employee_id    supervisor_email manager_01_email    manager_02_email  \
0         1011    steve.g@pool.com     fsg@pool.com  m.edwards@pool.com   
1         1012   x.alonso@pool.com     fsg@pool.com  m.edwards@pool.com   
2         1013    kenny.d@pool.com     fsg@pool.com  m.edwards@pool.com   
3         1014  brendan.r@pool.com     fsg@pool.com  m.edwards@pool.com   
4         1015     dirk.k@pool.com     fsg@pool.com  m.edwards@pool.com   

     manager_03_email    manager_04_email  attrition_rate  
0     dirk.k@pool.com    steve.g@pool.com            0.10  
1    kenny.d@pool.com   x.alonso@pool.com            0.25  
2    kenny.d@pool.com    kenny.d@pool.com            0.25  
3  brendan.r@pool.com  brendan.r@pool.com            0.35  
4     dirk.k@pool.com     dirk.k@pool.com             NaN
```

Comment: Thank u so much, I think the solution is almost there! There is a slight edit as I added the quarter column. For employee 1012 in y2022q2, the attrition_rate should be 0.6 instead of NaN as the higher level manager is m.edwards@pool.com at y2022q2. Was wondering if the code could factor in that it has to go higher up another hierarchy until it arrives at a non-null attrition_rate value